# Contravariant vector example with polar coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates, tensors

My book gives me this definition for contravariant vector:

*Let an n-tuple of real numbers $a^1,a^2, \dots, a^n$ be associated with a point P of an n-dimensional Riemannian space with coordinates $u^1,u^2, \dots, u^n$. Furthermore let there be associated with P an n-tuple of real number $b^1,b^2, \dots, b^n$ with respect to any coordinate system $v^1,v^2, \dots, v^n$ which can be obtained from the coordinates $u^{\alpha}$ by an allowable transformation. If these numbers satisfy the relations:*

$$ b^{\alpha} = \frac{\partial v^{\alpha}}{\partial u^{\beta}} a^{\beta} \qquad \alpha = 1, \dots, n $$

$$ a^{\alpha} = \frac{\partial u^{\alpha}}{\partial v^{\beta}} b^{\beta} \qquad \alpha = 1, \dots, n $$

*We say that a contravariant vector is given.*

Where the summation convention is intended. Now, because by ''allowable transformation'' the book intend that the function $u^{\alpha}(v^\beta)$ is of class $r \geqslant 1$ and the inverse transformation $v^{\alpha}(u^{\beta})$ exists and is of the same class, I want to carry the following example:

I want to prove by definition that, respect to cartesian coordinates the vector with coordinates $(1,1)$ is contravariant respect to a transformation in polar coordinates.

The transformation in polar coordinates is $C^{\infty}$ so is by definition an allowable transformation. I will then have :

$$ a^{\beta} = (1,1) \qquad b^{\alpha} = (\sqrt{2}, \frac{\pi}{4}) $$

And:

$$ \begin{cases} u^1 = v^1\cos v^2 \\ u^2 = v^1\sin v^2 \end{cases} \qquad \begin{cases} v^1 = \sqrt{(u^1)^2 + (u^2)^2}\\ v^2 = \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{u^2}{u^1} \right) \end{cases} $$

But, if I plug these information in the contravariant definition, for instance:

$$ a^{2} = \frac{\partial u^{2}}{\partial v^{\beta}} b^{\beta} \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad 1 = \sqrt{2}\sin v^2 + \frac{\pi}{4}v^1\cos v^2 $$

Which is false. So, where is my error ?

P.S. I already proved that for linear transformations, or rotations, the definition holds. My question is why doesnt'hold for a common transformation like this, which seems to have all the requisites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting confused between the coordinates themselves (non-linear, describe points) and the associated frames (linear, describe vectors). In non-linear coordinates (and necessarily in non-flat Riemannian spaces) we need to make the distinction between points and vectors.

When you convert $(1,1) \to (\sqrt 2, \pi/4)$, you're talking expressing a *point* by its $(r,\theta)$ coordinates rather than by its $(x,y)$ ones. If $b$ is meant to be a vector instead, then the components $b^\alpha$ are the numbers such that $b = \sum_\alpha b^\alpha e_\alpha$ for $e_\alpha = \partial {\bf x} / \partial v^\alpha$ the coordinate frame associated to $v$.

Comment: So what are the values of $b^{\alpha}$ ? I have that the coordinate frame associated to v is: $$ e_{v^2}=(-v^1 \sin v^2, v^1 \cos v^2) \qquad e_{v^1}=(\cos v^2, \sin v^2) $$ But isn't clear to me how to find $b^{\alpha}$ values.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to completely determine the answer. You need (1) a tuple $(u^1, u^2)$ that describes a point in Cartesian coordinates, (2) a tuple $(a^1, a^2)$ that describes a direction as a linear combination of the Cartesian basis vectors, and (3) a function that transforms the Cartesian coordinates $(u^1, u^2)$ to the polar coordinates $(v^1, v^2)$, which you already have. Once you have *all* these pieces of information, you can find the tuple $(b^1, b^2)$.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. The point in cartesian coordinates is the one I've already specified P=(1,1), for the vector in cartesian coordinates I mean the one that points to P from to origin of the reference frame: $$ \vec{v} = \vec{e}_1 + \vec{e}_2 $$ Respect to the canonical basis.

Comment: No, you're still conflating positions with vectors. As an example, it would be entirely well-formed for me to say I want to consider the vector $(a^1, a^2) = (1, 1)$ at the point $(u^1, u^2) = (3, 5)$.  That's because the vector need not have any relationship to the coordinates of position.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you say, but I have another question: if I consider an affine space my reasoning is still wrong ?